# random increasing sequence with O(1) access to any element?

Tags: algorithm, math, random, random-access

I have an interesting math/CS problem.  I need to sample from a possibly infinite random sequence of increasing values, X, with X(i) > X(i-1),  with some distribution between them.  You could think of this as the sum of a different sequence D of uniform random numbers in [0,d).  This is easy to do if you start from the first one and go from there; you just add a random amount to the sum each time.  But the catch is, I want to be able to get any element of the sequence in faster than O(n) time, ideally O(1), without storing the whole list.  To be concrete, let's say I pick d=1, so one possibility for D (given a particular seed) and its associated X is:

```
D={.1, .5, .2, .9, .3, .3, .6 ...}  // standard random sequence, elements in [0,1)
X={.1, .6, .8, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.9, ...} // increasing random values; partial sum of D
```

(I don't really care about D, I'm just showing one conceptual way to construct X, my sequence of interest.)  Now I want to be able to compute the value of X[1] or X[1000] or X[1000000] equally fast, without storing all the values of X or D.  Can anyone point me to some clever algorithm or a way to think about this?

(Yes, what I'm looking for is random access into a random sequence -- with two different meanings of random.  Makes it hard to google for!)

Comment: Maybe you could do it sort of like a skip list, i.e. store the sum for e.g. half the list, 3/4 the list, 7/8 the list, etc., and use those and the original list to calculate the sums for the values in-between in (sort-of) O(log(n)) time. This way, the number of intermediate values for this the sum is stored is the trade-off between fast access and small memory footprint.

Comment: genisage: yes, that's true, but how can that help?  It's not exactly nd/2 and in parts of the sequence it can diverge arbitrarily far from that value.

Comment: tobias_k: this is a very good suggestion, thanks!  I'll look into it further.

Comment: You're SOL for information-theoretic reasons unless `D` is pseudorandom. How much tolerance is there in the definition of `D`?

Comment: David: yes, assume D is pseudorandom.  For instance D could be a sequence based on hashing the index with some salt.  That gives O(1) access to any element of D, which is a start... but still leaves the problem of the partial sums.  I'm hoping for a solution that removes the need to compute the Ds at all.

Comment: to get a `O(1)` access to any element, you need to make sure that you can get to any element in a constant number of steps, where that constant is not input-size dependent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `D` is pseudorandom, there’s a space-time tradeoff possible:
`O(sqrt(n))`-time retrievals using `O(sqrt(n))` storage locations (or,
in general, `O(n**alpha)`-time retrievals using `O(n**(1-alpha))`
storage locations). Assume zero-based indexing and that
`X[n] = D[0] + D[1] + ... + D[n-1]`. Compute and store

```
Y[s] = X[s**2]
```

for all `s**2 <= n` in the range of interest. To look up `X[n]`, let
`s = floor(sqrt(n))` and return
`Y[s] + D[s**2] + D[s**2+1] + ... + D[n-1]`.

EDIT: here's the start of an approach based on the following idea.

Let Dist(1) be the uniform distribution on [0, d) and let Dist(k) for k > 1 be the distribution of the sum of k independent samples from Dist(1). We need fast, deterministic methods to (i) pseudorandomly sample Dist(2**p) and (ii) given that X and Y are distributed as Dist(2**p), pseudorandomly sample X conditioned on the outcome of X + Y.

Now imagine that the D array constitutes the leaves of a complete binary tree of size 2**q. The values at interior nodes are the sums of the values at their two children. The naive way is to fill the D array directly, but then it takes a long time to compute the root entry. The way I'm proposing is to sample the root from Dist(2**q). Then, sample one child according to Dist(2**(q-1)) given the root's value. This determines the value of the other, since the sum is fixed. Work recursively down the tree. In this way, we look up tree values in time O(q).

Here's an implementation for Gaussian `D`. **I'm not sure it's working properly.**

```
import hashlib, math

def random_oracle(seed):
    h = hashlib.sha512()
    h.update(str(seed).encode())
    x = 0.0
    for b in h.digest():
        x = ((x + b) / 256.0)
    return x

def sample_gaussian(variance, seed):
    u0 = random_oracle((2 * seed))
    u1 = random_oracle(((2 * seed) + 1))
    return (math.sqrt((((- 2.0) * variance) * math.log((1.0 - u0)))) * math.cos(((2.0 * math.pi) * u1)))

def sample_children(sum_outcome, sum_variance, seed):
    difference_outcome = sample_gaussian(sum_variance, seed)
    return (((sum_outcome + difference_outcome) / 2.0), ((sum_outcome - difference_outcome) / 2.0))

def sample_X(height, i):
    assert (0 <= i <= (2 ** height))
    total = 0.0
    z = sample_gaussian((2 ** height), 0)
    seed = 1
    for j in range(height, 0, (- 1)):
        (x, y) = sample_children(z, (2 ** j), seed)
        assert (abs(((x + y) - z)) <= 1e-09)
        seed *= 2
        if (i >= (2 ** (j - 1))):
            i -= (2 ** (j - 1))
            total += x
            z = y
            seed += 1
        else:
            z = x
    return total

def test(height):
    X = [sample_X(height, i) for i in range(((2 ** height) + 1))]
    D = [(X[(i + 1)] - X[i]) for i in range((2 ** height))]
    mean = (sum(D) / len(D))
    variance = (sum((((d - mean) ** 2) for d in D)) / (len(D) - 1))
    print(mean, math.sqrt(variance))
    D.sort()
    with open('data', 'w') as f:
        for d in D:
            print(d, file=f)
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    test(10)
```

Comment: Nice -- this biases toward the low end (higher indices take longer) but the storage doesn't grow as fast as, for instance, just storing every Nth element of X.  However, it still does mean computing all D[n] up to the element of interest, at least once.

Comment: @GaryO I think there might be a way to get logarithmic-time retrievals with (let's say) polylog extra space. The idea would be staple an implicit Fenwick tree to some conditional sampling of X given X + Y, where X and Y are distributed as sums of a certain number of D entries. The details are a little complicated in this setting, which is why I asked about Gaussians (and then deleted the comment, since Gaussians have the wrong range).

Comment: David: can you say more?  I know what a Fenwick tree is (basically; I've done parallel prefix sums/scans) but not sure what you mean in the part starting with conditional sampling.

Comment: OK, this'll take some thought!  I see where you're going.  Dist(k) is asymptotically normal with large k.  But after sampling the root and one child (independently), what if the child sample is greater than the root?  Then the other child is negative which shouldn't happen.  Maybe that's what you mean by "given the root's value" -- you select the child sample from [0, root) using the given distribution.  In theory, this whole thing could be recomputed every time using zero storage, if the Dist(level, element, range, seed) is reproducible which it seems it ought to be.

Comment: @GaryO Yeah, the conditional distribution aspect is what makes this tricky. I'm going to try to post working code for Gaussians all the way down. One hack to get it to be nondecreasing would be to resample child values that are larger than the parent. I have no clue whether that's a good idea.

Comment: @GaryO Specifically, resample the Gaussians until they're in range for what's possible for a sum of the specified number of uniform samples. Near the leaves, where the distribution is further from normal, switch to some other algorithm to sample uniforms conditioned on their sum (perhaps use the algorithm to sample k nonnegative numbers that sum to S until all of them are in range?).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not record the values in X, and if you do not remember the values in X you have previously generate, there is no way to guarantee that the elements in X you generate (on the fly) will be in increasing order. It furthermore seems like there is no way to avoid O(n) time worst-case per query, if you don't know how to quickly generate the CDF for the sum of the first m random variables in D for any choice of m.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there maybe some particular form of D that would be easy to generate the CDF you mention?  I'm not wedded to D being uniform or even that D(i) should be independent of D(i-1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the i<sup>th</sup> value X(i) from a *particular* realization, I can't see how you could do this without generating the sequence up to i.  Perhaps somebody else can come up with something clever.

Would you be willing to accept a value which is plausible in the sense that it has the same distribution as the X(i)'s you would observe across multiple realizations of the X process? If so, it should be pretty easy.  X(i) will be asymptotically normally distributed with mean `i/2` (since it's the sum of the D<sub>k</sub>'s for `k=1,...,i`, the D's are Uniform(0,1), and the expected value of a D is 1/2) and variance `i/12` (since the variance of a D is 1/12 and the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of their variances).

Because of the asymptotic aspect, I'd pick some threshold value for i to switch over from direct summing to using the normal. For example, if you use i = 12 as your threshold you would use actual summing of uniforms for values of i from 1 to 11, and generate a `Normal(i/2, sqrt(i/12))` value for i >.  That's an O(1) algorithm since the total work is bounded by your threshold, and the results produced will be distributionally representative of what you would see if you actually went through the summing.

Comment: Yes, I'd be willing to accept something "plausible" -- good way to put it!  But it does have to obey X(i) > X(i-1) for all i, and your algorithm doesn't always do that I think.

Comment: On the plausibility idea, maybe X could be "pinned" to particular values, like exactly M/2, every M samples (for largeish M).  Then I could start at the appropriate multiple of M and compute from there without having to compute all Ds up to there.  It's still not an easy problem though to compute this "pinned" X so it has a plausible distribution of the M values between X[Mn] and X[M(n+1)].

Comment: An alternative would be to generate specific X(i)'s, but then generate near neighbors conditionally by adding or subtracting short sequences of uniforms or faking larger lags by adding or subtracting normals.  This would mean logging the specific X(i)'s you have already created so they can be used as anchor points.